# How do I make a on_mentioned event in Nextcord python?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, nextcord

I want to make my Discord bot tell a member not to ping the owner.

I'm not too sure if **on_mentioned** is an actual event. If anybody can help,
that'd be a huge help.

Here's what I'm working with at the moment:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_mentioned(ctx):
    author = ctx.author.mention

    await ctx.send(f'{author} please do not ping that member. They are either AFK or do not want to be pinged.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for mentions in on_message.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    for mention in message.mentions:
        # do something
```

[`message.mentions`](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/latest/api.html#nextcord.Message.mentions) will be a list of users mentioned, you can check if it contains any mentions or not.

Note about overriding on_message -- the bot will not process commands if you override this without running bot.process_commands(). You can alternatively, use a listener. See https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working.

> I'm not too sure if on_mentioned is an actual event

That's what docs are for. You can check the [Event Reference](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/latest/api.html#event-reference) or search for it.

Comment: Okay, I haven't used Nextcord that much. But, how could I make it delete the message that has the mention?

Comment: You can check the docs (message object), `await message.delete()`